# Increase value of TextView e.g. 0 as clicked value +1

Tags: java, android, textview

I am developing my program but it seems It really giving me hard time regarding TextView.XD
Just like in Scoreboard. Increasing the value of score as you click the TextView assigned to it.

This is my code:

```
private OnClickListener mHscoreListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //DO INCREASE
        h1++;
        TextView HScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hscore);
        HScore.setText(h1);
    };
};
```

The above code not working and I don't know why.

Comment: You may need to post more code. Have you set your button's onClickListener with .setOnClickListener()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set onClickListener to TextView HScore.

Try this way 
Define HScore and h1 as class variable.

```
HScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hscore);
OnClickListener mHscoreListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
     // DO INCREASE
     h1++;
     HScore.setText(h1 + "");
    };
};
HScore.setOnClickListener(mHscoreListener);
```

Comment: @Catherine grace Balauro   :) Pleasure

Answer (score 0):

What type is `h1`?

You may need to use `h1.toString()`

```
private OnClickListener mHscoreListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //DO INCREASE
        h1++;
        TextView HScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hscore);
        HScore.setText(h1.toString());
    };
};
```

Comment: If it's a string, then the `++` operator won't work on it.  If it's an int, `setText()` won't accept it as a parameter.  (Your compiler will tell you that this is the problem, if you bother to read the error message.)

Comment: h1 is an integer. hscore has a value of 0. i want it as to increase +1 as you click the textview: hscore.. Is it possible? string to int. int to string, like that. thanks

Comment: Catherine, try the above mentioned `toString()` method in `setText()` to get the `String` value of the `int`.

Comment: yes it works thanks willtate. But How would the value of h1 increase the value? e.g. from 0 to +1. just like in basketball scoreboard.  should I use charsequence?

Comment: For future reference, an int can be turned into a string using `String.valueOf(myint)` and a string can be turned into an int using `Integer.parseInt(myString)`